# ASP.net core application targetting framework 4.6 unable to resolve for .NETFramework version 4.6

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, active-directory

I created a .net core application that I have targetted at the full .net 4.6 framework in order to use System.DirectoryServices to connect to Active Directory. I have changed the csproj file as below adding net46 to target framework and adding system.directoryservices.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <!--<TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>-->
  <TargetFramework>net46</TargetFramework>
  <PackageTargetFallback>portable-net45+win8</PackageTargetFallback>
  <UserSecretsId>fdd24e9b-cd56-499e-9c1b-f8ef2b24ba09</UserSecretsId>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.1.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="1.1.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="System.DirectoryServices" Version="4.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

This all works as expected, I can reload project, and use the directory services in full. I have now attempted to add System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement in the same way as adding System.DirectoryServices as below:

```
  <PackageReference Include="System.DirectoryServices" Version="4.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement" Version="4.0.0" />
```

Yet when I attempt to reload the project I get the following error:

[Unable to resolve error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgPxc.png)

The error implies to me that the .net 4.6 framework does not contain the AccountManagement package, yet it should be available any above 4.0.

I am new to development in asp .net core, so I assume that I am missing something trivial, so any explanation of this issue would be great.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project file needs to look like this,

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net46</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x86</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

And the last one is a normal reference, not package reference.

Comment: Thanks! Adding AccountManagement as a reference rather than a packagereference worked.